# Replace fragment in Android by clearing the existing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an application in which i have a side menu.When each item is clicked,fragments are replaced with new ones.

I have a method for this replacing of fragments.But the fragments are overlapped instead of replacing.The old fragment lies in the background and new ones are placed on the top of old ones.

This is my method for replacing fragments.

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment){

    resideMenu.clearIgnoredViewList();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "fragment")
            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .commit();

}
```

How to clear the old fragment before placing the new one ?

Edit:

```
 private void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment){

    resideMenu.clearIgnoredViewList();
    FragmentTransaction ft = (FragmentTransaction) getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "fragment")
            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();



}
```

Comment: This is because the background for fragments are transparent so it will show you as a overlapped fragments. So avoid this you need to set background color or background image for particular fragment in your xml file.

Comment: Its not about the background color.I have a webview which has some youtube videos which is getting played even if i change the fragment.It plays in background which is against YouTube policies.I need to clear it somehow.

Comment: Your code now removes the fragment and then tries to replace a fragment.  I think the second op should be .new not .replace.

Comment: would you please share your fragment onCreateView method code block... i think problem is there....

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code. Just remove previous fragment.. :D

```
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(fragment instanceof MessageInbox ){

                PRODUCT_FLAG=0;
            }
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I always give a fragment a tag when it is created. It is much easier to find it afterwards.  Then you can use code like this:

```
// DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
// in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
// dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
            if (prev != null) {
                ft.remove(prev);
            }
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

      // Create and show the dialog.
DialogFragment newFragment = new GrowLogDialogFragment();
newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 1);
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "dialog");
```

Comment: Please see edited question.I changed my method to that.Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                                    .beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "fragment");
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);// this line do that
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this on `onpause` or `ondetach`

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{

        if (fragment != null) {
               FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.remove(fragment);
               ft.commit();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         Thread.interrupted();
    super.onPause();
}
```

}